# iOS application not work on some devices

Tags: ios, crash-log

I have created my first swift/objective c application and publish it to the store

the application is working fine in simulator (8.1, 9.2)
I have also test it on different device and it is working without any problems for example

iPhone 4 (9.2), iPhone 5 (9.3.1), iPhone 6 (9.3)

but some users say that it is not working on their devices and send me the following log

```
app_name":"Khwater","app_version":"1.0.4","bundleID":"com.Khwater","adam_id":961222355,"os_version":"iPhone OS 8.1.1 (12B436)","slice_uuid":"18a22c9d-fbe7-3247-b793-bf67d2c4d9b6","share_with_app_devs":false,"build_version":"1.0.4","is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","name":"Khwater"}
Incident Identifier: DB55D287-009E-4667-B097-101E88CEC8E2
CrashReporter Key:   376dbf063334348fe769ebdcec21f8f4e1cb5226
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Process:             Khwater [976]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/6C0A1CB8-A845-421E-B6EE-C56F89E498F2/Khwater.app/Khwater
Identifier:          com.Khwater
Version:             1.0.4 (1.0.4)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-03-10 22:02:26.690 +0300
Launch Time:         2015-03-10 22:02:24.453 +0300
OS Version:          iOS 8.1.1 (12B436)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000cf97beb8
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019677bbd0 0x196760000 + 113616
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185ef5224 0x185ef0000 + 21028
2   QuartzCore                      0x000000018a11c640 0x18a110000 + 50752
3   QuartzCore                      0x000000018a122494 0x18a110000 + 74900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185ef5224 0x185ef0000 + 21028
5   QuartzCore                      0x000000018a124f68 0x18a110000 + 85864
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196dad368 0x196dac000 + 4968
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196db197c 0x196dac000 + 22908
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185fcdfa0 0x185ef0000 + 909216
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185fcc048 0x185ef0000 + 901192
10  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185ef90a0 0x185ef0000 + 37024
11  GraphicsServices                0x000000018f09b5a0 0x18f090000 + 46496
12  UIKit                           0x000000018a82e3bc 0x18a7b8000 + 484284
13  Khwater                         0x00000001000c9b88 0x100054000 + 482184
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000196dd6a04 0x196dd4000 + 10756

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196ed4c94 0x196ed4000 + 3220
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196dbc97c 0x196dac000 + 67964
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196daf3b0 0x196dac000 + 13232

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196eefc78 0x196ed4000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196f89390 0x196f88000 + 5008
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196f88fa4 0x196f88000 + 4004

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196eefc78 0x196ed4000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196f89390 0x196f88000 + 5008
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196f88fa4 0x196f88000 + 4004

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196eefc78 0x196ed4000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196f89390 0x196f88000 + 5008
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196f88fa4 0x196f88000 + 4004

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196ed4e7c 0x196ed4000 + 3708
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196ed4cf4 0x196ed4000 + 3316
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185fcdecc 0x185ef0000 + 909004
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185fcbe20 0x185ef0000 + 900640
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185ef90a0 0x185ef0000 + 37024
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001859fe4e4 0x185960000 + 648420
6   Foundation                      0x0000000186ee9c08 0x186df4000 + 1006600
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196f8be7c 0x196f88000 + 15996
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196f8bdd8 0x196f88000 + 15832
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196f88fac 0x196f88000 + 4012

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196eef498 0x196ed4000 + 111768
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185fd38c4 0x185ef0000 + 932036
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196f8be7c 0x196f88000 + 15996
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196f8bdd8 0x196f88000 + 15832
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196f88fac 0x196f88000 + 4012

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196eefc78 0x196ed4000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196f89390 0x196f88000 + 5008
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196f88fa4 0x196f88000 + 4004

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x00000001701d03b0   x1: 0x0000000192d06778   x2: 0x0000000000000008   x3: 0x0000000196f29a74
    x4: 0x000000016fdaa568   x5: 0x0000000000000001   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x00000001973e6000   x9: 0x00000000cf97bea8  x10: 0x0000000000000105  x11: 0x00000001973f4df0
   x12: 0x00000001702e1100  x13: 0xbadda1cccf97bead  x14: 0x00000000c3000004  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x000000019677bbc0  x17: 0x00000001967824dc  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x00000001701d03b0
   x20: 0x00000001701d03b8  x21: 0x00000001973e99e8  x22: 0x000000018afad448  x23: 0x000000017403f2c0
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x00000001024e10f0  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x000000019aa5c7c0  fp: 0x000000016fdaa9e0   lr: 0x0000000185ef5228
    sp: 0x000000016fdaa980   pc: 0x000000019677bbd0 cpsr: 0x20000000

Binary Images:
0x100054000 - 0x1000e7fff Khwater arm64  <18a22c9dfbe73247b793bf67d2c4d9b6> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/6C0A1CB8-A845-421E-B6EE-C56F89E498F2/Khwater.app/Khwater
0x120040000 - 0x120067fff dyld arm64  <36eff49275c23d2d815e48af33eea471> /usr/lib/dyld
0x1847f0000 - 0x184983fff AVFoundation arm64  <c9cd60a62cfb3e77be72db6cd3062a09> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x184984000 - 0x1849e8fff libAVFAudio.dylib arm64  <017d90360b443ae788ef31cfd73d17f6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib
0x1849ec000 - 0x184a2bfff AVKit arm64  <8eb98ea09dfe3b218fd8a71197a85ad2> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVKit.framework/AVKit
0x184a2c000 - 0x184a2cfff Accelerate arm64  <e9ba7838f51634a7b59ed392be50e86f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x184a44000 - 0x184c63fff vImage arm64  <da44067fc79931c7aef1b7e88bf82a83> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x184c64000 - 0x184d0bfff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <e5276e7784ef34a4baca480264978ea0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x184d0c000 - 0x185086fff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <165b05f9f75736d5ae8f5f39293bd6e7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x185088000 - 0x18509dfff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <5574ec3bd4e537e1b662d38a63aec58b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x1850a0000 - 0x185108fff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <004f5668574139bc906c5fa4fdced3b1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x18510c000 - 0x18512ffff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <5790e7ace143367ea6f2428852be384e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x185130000 - 0x185130fff vecLib arm64  <211d7711a6e93fe8ae6d6b42585cad2d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x185134000 - 0x185162fff Accounts arm64  <2508d336b9893176ad4e1bc67ff04188> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x185164000 - 0x185164fff AdSupport arm64  <977faefc983d3d72ad5e531740e4130a> /System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport
0x185168000 - 0x1851eafff AddressBook arm64  <09e2e24ef5e23fb8a62ae209466a64bd> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x1851ec000 - 0x18533cfff AddressBookUI arm64  <e79239b432af33e783296d2a9841578e> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x185340000 - 0x185353fff AssetsLibrary arm64  <9bf190e7f6403dd4bf42085fd4046c7d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary
0x185504000 - 0x1857c1fff AudioToolbox arm64  <f0b739a395993b808d66e85e1a6e9f18> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x185960000 - 0x185b6bfff CFNetwork arm64  <68adcebf440d30769bd2d67adc7932a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFN ......
```

can any one please help me to solve this problem and understand what is going on?

Comment: That is an iPhone 6 running iOS 8.1.1. You should be able to add the symbols back into the crash report and get more info from the stack trace.

Comment: There are dozens of well written posts about that. You can Google it.